# jQuery UI Range Slider, before change event or get value without changing?

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery UI Range slider https://jqueryui.com/slider/#range and I want to click between the two points and get the value of where I clicked, without initiating a change event.  So the two points wouldn't move.  There isn't a before change event.

```
$("#slider-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: min,
    max: max,
    step: 1,
    values: [start, end],
    create: function( event, ui ) {
        update_tooltips(0);
    },
    change: function( event, ui ) {
        var index = ui.handleIndex;
        var seconds = ui.value;
    }
});
```

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There isn't a before change event.

No, but you were on the right track.  I expermiented with [all the available methods](https://api.jqueryui.com/slider/), and found a few things:

- if you click on the slider track, the sequence of events is `.start()`, `.slide()`, `.stop()`, `.change()`;
- All methods receive the `event` as a paramter, and in the `.start()` method, we can identify if the click was on a handle by inspecting the `event.originalEvent.target`;
- The `event` target info is different by the time we reach the `.slide()` method, AFAICT we can no longer find out what was originally clicked at this point.  So we have to track what was clicked before we get here;
- [The `slide()` docs say](https://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-slide):

  > The value provided in the event as ui.value represents the value that the handle will have as a result of the current movement. Canceling the event will prevent the handle from moving

  So this is the key - we can get the clicked value, but we can still cancel the actual change.  It doesn't describe how to *cancel the event*, but I tried `return false;` and that does the trick;

Putting all this together:

```js
let min = 0, max = 100;
let start = 20, end = 80;

// Add a variable to track where the click was
let clickOnHandle;

$("#slider-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: min,
    max: max,
    step: 1,
    values: [start, end],
    create: function( event, ui ) {
        console.log('create');
    },
    start: function(event, ui) {
        // Add a start handler, where we can investigate what was clicked
        console.log('start');
                
        // If this was a click on a handle, it will have this class. 
        // Track that boolean result with our variable.
        clickOnHandle = $(event.originalEvent.target).hasClass('ui-slider-handle');
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        console.log('stop');
    },
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        // Add a slide handler
        console.log('slide', ui.value);
        
        // If the click was not on a handle, we can bail out and stop
        // the actual change from happening, while still getting the
        // clicked value.
        if (! clickOnHandle) {
            $('#clicked').text(ui.value);
            return false;
        }
        
        // If this was a real change, update the display
        $('#value').text(ui.value);
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
        console.log('change');
    }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="slider-range"></div>

<div>
    <p>Current Value: <span id="value">20</span></p>
    <p>Clicked Value: <span id="clicked"></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated.